# Print tree data in hierarchy with blanks and gaps

Tags: sql, tree

I have a 3 SQL table with tree nodes and tree leaves and node description
I want to print the data in the following format

```
Parent6 Parent5 Parent4 Parent3 Parent1 Child Description
                 A1
                         B1
                                 C1    
                                          D1A  - Child 1
                                          D1B  - Child 2
                                 C2
                                          D2A - Child 3
                                          D2B - Child 4
                         B2
```

I have TreeNodeNuM, TreeName, Level in Node Table

Comment: Things like this should be done on application/presentation layer, **not in the database**.

Comment: (1) Provide sample data.  (2) Tag your question with the database you are using.

Answer (score 0):

I made this code for a similar thing, I normally use only the LongID and LongDescription columns for my needs, I added the cases to make the output similar to your example, note that the level starts in 0 for my hierarchy

```
WITH cte AS
  (
    SELECT     CAST(RIGHT('000' + CAST(HierarchyID AS VARCHAR),3) AS VARCHAR(100)) as M,
               CAST(Description AS VARCHAR(MAX)) AS LongID, *
    FROM       HIERARCHY
    WHERE Level = 0
    UNION ALL
    SELECT     CAST(cte.M + '_' + RIGHT('000' + CAST(si.HierarchyID AS varchar), 3) AS VARCHAR(100)),
               CAST(cte.LongID + '->' + si.Description AS VARCHAR(MAX)),
               si.*
    FROM       HIERARCHY si
    INNER JOIN cte
    ON si.ParentHierarchyID = cte.HierarchyID
  )
  SELECT 
  CASE WHEN Level = 0 THEN Description ELSE '' END AS Parent6,
  CASE WHEN Level = 1 THEN Description ELSE '' END AS Parent5,
  CASE WHEN Level = 2 THEN Description ELSE '' END AS Parent4,
  CASE WHEN Level = 3 THEN Description ELSE '' END AS Parent3,
  CASE WHEN Level = 4 THEN Description ELSE '' END AS Parent1,
  CASE WHEN Level = 5 THEN Description ELSE '' END AS Child, 
  FROM cte
  ORDER BY LongID
```